# Equivalent definition of cograph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

A cograph is simple graph defined by the criteria

1. $K_1$ is a cograph,
2. If X is a cograph, then so is its graph complement, and
3. If X and Y are cographs, then so is their graph union X union Y

and also it is said that a graph is called cograph if G does not contain the path graph $P_4$ as an induced subgraph. How these definition are equivalent or atleast how first one is implying second? I am totally struck in which direction to proceed. Any reference or hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that the first definition implies the second, you can use induction on $n$, the number of vertices.
The base case is trivial.  For the induction step, the cograph $G$ can be obtained either by the union of two smaller cographs $G_1$ and $G_2$, or by complementing such a graph.

In the first case, apply induction on both $G_1$ and $G_2$ to deduce that $G$ has no $P_4$.  In the second case, $G$ is obtained by complementing a cograph $G'$ obtained from the union of two cographs.  We just argued that $G'$ is $P_4$-free, so it suffices to observe that the complement of a $P_4$ is a $P_4$, and that complementing a graph without a $P_4$ cannot create one.

In the other direction (defintion 2 implies definition 1), the proof I know of relies on the fact that if $G$ is a $P_4$-free graph, then for any $X \subseteq V(G)$, one of $G[X]$ or the complement of $G[X]$ is disconnected ($G[X]$ denotes the subgraph induced by $X$).  It's provable by induction.  Then, this fact can be used to show that $G$ was obtained by taking the union of two cographs, or by complementing it.

EDIT :

The full proof can be find on page 6, Theorem 19 of this document : 
https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgax/Graph-Theory-notes.pdf

Comment: @ Manuel, Can you elaborate induction step.

Comment: You mean in the first direction (2nd paragraph of the answer) ?

Comment: ''G is a P4-free graph, then for any X⊆V(G), one of G[X] or the complement of G[X] is disconnected''

Comment: I have edited the answer with a link to a proof.

Comment: @ Manuel, Thanks.